# Camel Restlet - Binding query parameters to message headers

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

Looking through **Camel** docs I couldn't find any way that allow me to bind the query parameters within the headers. For example :

Let's say I have an endpoint like that
http://localhost:8080/services/resource?filter=xxx

End I want to get that parameter from the header 
exchange.getIn.().getHeaders().get('filter')

The query parameter 'filter' is not returned in the header. Anyone of you knows if this feature is coming by default in camel? I know I can build the binding by myself, but i am just looking for choose among **camel-servlet** (apparently that binding is implemented by default) and **camel-restlet**.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose **camel-restlet** you can use the

```
restletBinding=#refName
```

to convert the query string parameters to headers.

The **#refName** is the bean ID of a RestletBinding object in the Camel Registry.